# Stack Overflow broken with Firefox and Adblock Plus

Tags: support, firefox

I'm using Firefox 61.0.2 (64-bit) with Adblock Plus, and since today, Stack Overflow is completely broken for me. It looks like this:

[image: Nearly blank screen due to none of the CSS and almost none of the images loading.]

Console output:

[image: Multiple reference errors saying StackExchange is not defined.]

When using Chrome or disabling Adblock, everything is looking fine.

Comment: Check the console, do you see any error?

Comment: [MSE dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314566/369403). I can copy-paste the answer here, if that's desired.

Answer (score 11):

Update EasyList, a faulty automated commit caused the problem. See https://github.com/easylist/easylist/commit/41eb1d2456a7f23fd8331ff9962f20686c4fa0bf#commitcomment-30261865