# The page does not load correctly

Tags: support, google-chrome

Google chrome browser, Windows 10 operating system.

On another browser works correctly (I checked on Internet Explorer).

I noticed the problem yesterday. Problem only for the site https://stackoverflow.com

Below screenshot from the screen.

[image]

I am reporting the bug for the first time, I could forget about something.

Comment: Are you using any userscripts or addons?

Comment: After turning off Adblock is okay, I would not think about it. It worked well before :) @SurajRao

Comment: Might be related to this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372970/stack-overflow-broken-with-firefox-and-adblock-plus

Comment: Yes, but when I asked a question I did not even think about adblock, so I could not find a solution anywhere. @yivi